# Exact formulation of Paley-Zygmund inequality

Tags: probability-inequalities

The Paley-Zygmund inequality states that $P(X \succ c\mathbb{E}[x]) \succ (1-c)^2 \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]^2}{\mathbb{E}[X^2]}$ for $X\succ 0$ and $0\prec c \prec 1$.

I've used $\succ$ here because I have seen this formula with pretty much any combination of $>$ and $\geq$ plugged in for the various instances of $\succ$.I guess for continuous random variables this sloppiness doesn't matter much in practice, but what is the exact formula here?

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality) is clear on this.  Because it offers a proof, it also affords you the opportunity to check its accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the probability function, if we allow equality, we increase the probability. Hence, the inequality is stronger if we do not allow equality there. Outside of the probability, the statement is strengthened if we allow equality. For the condition on $X$, we increase the strength of the statement if we allow equality. The same holds for $c$ (i.e., $0$ and $1$ should be allowed). So, we get the strongest statement if we state that for any $X\ge 0$ and $0\le c \le 1$, 
$P(X > c \mathbb{E}[X]) \ge (1-c)^2 \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]^2}{\mathbb{E}[X^2]}$. And so one should use this form.

Having said this, the statement also requires $\mathbb{E}[X^2]>0$, or in the lower bound we get $0/0$, which has no meaning. Also, $c=1$ gives a vacuous statement, so it is not crucial to allow $c=1$ in the statement.